# Does the Facebook Scribe Server support authenticating its clients and securing the client/server connection? 

Tags: logging, heroku, amazon-ec2, scribe-server

I plan on running a Facebook Scribe Server on an AWS EC2 providing logging services to several Heroku hosted Rails clients.

Is there a mechanism to authenticate Scribe clients in cloud-based scenarios like one described above? If so, can the resulting connections be secured using SSL?

Comment: 1) Off-topic, system administration questions belong on http://www.serverfault.com. 2) What difference does it make if the server is hosted by Amazon, Rackspace or sitting in your bedroom? Your server doesn't know it's in Amazon's building or that it's running in a virtualization container.

Comment: Thanks for the advise redarding posting this sto serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is this [pull request](https://github.com/facebook/scribe/pull/44) I submitted that uses SSL not only for transmission, but also for host verification.

You probably wouldn't be able to use it in Heroku, though. :-(

Comment: Looks promising. Given our security requirements, we went with RabbitMQ.